# How do you increase your rizq?

Tags: salat, money

If you pray your salahs regularly and ask for an increase in wealth, but your wealth decreases, is that a test?

How do you increase your rizq(sustenance) and wealth?

Comment: Increase in wealth and increase in rizk is different... for example increase in wealth is related to everything that you can buy from your wealth, while increasing in rizk is only the food you eat, and that increase in rizk does not mean that you earned one piece of bread now your earning 2 piece of bread. It can be like barkat in rizk if you dont know what barkat is then ask me i'll be sure to explain

Answer (score 1):

> but your wealth decreases, is that a test?

No one will have the definitive answer!

It might be, it might not

Allah says in surat ibrahim aya 7:

> وَإِذْ تَأَذَّنَ رَبُّكُمْ لَئِن شَكَرْتُمْ لَأَزِيدَنَّكُمْ ۖ وَلَئِن كَفَرْتُمْ إِنَّ عَذَابِي لَشَدِيدٌ

Which translates into:

> And [remember] when your Lord proclaimed, 'If you are grateful, I will surely increase you [in favor]; but if you deny, indeed, My punishment is severe.' "

As one might understand, the greatest sources of rizq is being thankful

Answer (score 0):

Answer: In my opinion it doesn't matter if it is a test or not, as long as you are content with what God has given you and you give thanks(both verbally and through actions).

A note on Du'a:

Du'a is often cited as the link between a person and God, because you are asking him directly for your needs both spiritual and worldly. So sincere Du'a and prayer is the way to go. But, as Abdullah Geith had mentioned, giving thanks to God is also a source of increase in rizq and required for the sustenance of this wealth.

I would also like to add that Istighfar is also a major source of increase in material and spiritual wealth.

Allah says in surat Nouh, verse 10:

> فَقُلْتُ اسْتَغْفِرُواْ رَبَّكُمْ إِنَّهُ كَانَ غَفَّاراً - يُرْسِلِ السَّمَآءَ عَلَيْكُمْ مُدْرَاراً 
>   - وَيُمْدِدْكُمْ بِأَمْوَلٍ وَبَنِينَ وَيَجْعَل لَّكُمْ جَنَّـتٍ وَيَجْعَل لَّكُمْ أَنْهَاراً - مَّا لَكُمْ لاَ تَرْجُونَ لِلَّهِ وَقَاراً

Translation:

> I said (to them): Ask forgiveness from your Lord, verily, He is Oft-Forgiving; - He will send rain to you Midrar - And give you increase in wealth and children, and bestow on you gardens and bestow on you rivers - What is the matter with you, that you do not hope for any Waqar from Allah

Giving thanks to God and Istighfar are not only words but actions too. If you are committing or had committed a sin, you have to repent to god and ask for his forgiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Rizq is in the hands of Allah (swt), therefore, worrying it will decrease or increase is not really important. We worry about things that are in our possession and things we have collected over the years. However, the two most prized possession we worry about (and we assume are ours) are our lives and wealth. But Allah (swt) reminds us these things are not ours, for He has purchased them from us. Here is an explanation of Rizq and who controls it https://www.islamiqate.com/1331/control-our-own-provisions-has-allah-swt-given-our-sustenance.